# How Can I pass OUT parameter to MySQL Stored Procedure when use RepoDB

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to call Stored Procedure on MySQL with out parameter.

I defined Stored Procedure as below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'GetPerson' ( IN '_accountId' bigint, OUT '_returnValue' int)

BEGIN
    SELECT AccountId, Age from Person where AccountId = _accountId ;
    SET _returnValue = 0;
END
```

And I write code using RepoDB

```
    public sealed class MyCustomMySQLDbSetting : BaseDbSetting
    {
        public MyCustomMySQLDbSetting()
            : base()
        {
            IsDirectionSupported = true;
        }
    }

DbSettingMapper.Add(typeof(MySqlConnection), new MyCustomMySQLDbSetting(), true);

using (var connection = MySqlClientFactory.Instance.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    var param = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "_accountId", 10 },
                    { "_returnValue", "0" },
                };

    var person = connection.ExecuteQuery<Person>(
        "GetPerson",
        param,
        commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

and I got

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine 
db.GetPerson is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Data:
  Server Error Code: 1414
```

I've tried param as below, got same result.

```
var param = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "_accountId", 10 },
    { "@_returnValue", 0 },
};
```

Is there any way pass OUT parameter to Stored Procedure with RepoDB ?

Comment: No, RepoDB does not allow output parameter. Maybe something that we can consider in the future if that's becoming a common use-cases. Question though, what are you trying to return in your '_returnValue' output parameter? If that is a newly identity id or whatever, you can just simply select back the value via 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();' and use the `var id = ExecuteScalar<long>(sp_name)` method.

Comment: I try to change Legacy Dapper code to RepoDB, there are many SP using _returnValue as SP success code or affected Rows, which depends on context. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

As of [v1.12.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RepoDb/1.12.6), the library started the support to the [DirectionalQueryField](https://repodb.net/class/directionalqueryfield#directionalqueryfield) object. It enables you to retrieve the value of the `OUTPUT` parameter from the database.

Let us say, you have the stored procedure below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Multiply]
(
    @Value1 DOUBLE
    , @Value2 DOUBLE
    , @Output DOUBLE OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Output = @Value1 * @Value2;
END
```

Then, you can call it like below.

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var output = new DirectionalQueryField("Output", typeof(double), ParamDirection.Output);
    var param = new []
    {
        new QueryField("Value1", 100),
        new QueryField("Value2", 200),
        output
    };
    var result = connection.ExecuteNonQuery("sp_Multiply", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    // Use the 'output' here like below
    var value = output.GetValue<double>(); // Or, you can also access the parameter itself like `output.Parameter.Value`
}
```